# ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll not working

Tags: apache, wamp, php-5.3, ioncube

I have tried following steps to enable ionCube PHP Loader

1) Download the Free IonCube Loaders for Windows VC9 (Non-TS) (32 bits)

2) After downloading, extract that zip pack to your wamp folder directly. So, that it becomes like this, `C:\wamp\ioncube`

3) Edit php.ini file: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini` and add this line at the bottom of the last line: `zend_extension = “C:\wamp\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll”`

4)Restart WAMP

But when i check in the php info its not displaying

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: With a Apache that old it is possible that it was compiled with VC6. Try the VC6 ioncube.

Answer (score 0):

If you really downloaded `ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll` as in question title, you inserted there incorrect line:

```
C:\wamp\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll
```

and it should be 5.3 instead of 5.2

If you save it and it will still not work, you should simple download [IonCube Loader Wizard](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.zip) which will help you to install it.

Comment: @NidhinRaj you have to simple unpack it, put into wamp www folder and run in browser, for example `http://localhost/ioncube/loader-wizard.php`. It will tell you exactly what you need to do

Comment: @NidhinRaj Have you completed all steps that wizard told you? It's rather impossible do it all in less than 1 minute.

Comment: @NidhinRaj  And what's this wizard telling you at the moment? That everything is fine? Have you restarted wamp after editing you php.ini file?

Comment: Are you sure you have edited the correct `php.ini` file? Just search all php.ini files in your system and make sure that line with ioncube is in all php.ini files and then restart your server again

Comment: @NidhinRaj  Sorry, I cannot help you then

Comment: when i do loader test i get one eror  **"The following problem has been found with the ionCube Loader installation:
You have a Windows loader but your server does not appear to be running Windows."**